# The instance member 'firstName' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to give default value to a TextFormField using text: parameter in it's controller

```
class _EditProfileState extends State<EditProfile> {

  String firstName = "Sushant";

  TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController(text: firstName);
```

But am getting the following error

```
The instance member 'firstName' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `late` with `TextEditingController` then initialize `TextEditingController` inside `initState`.

```
class _EditProfileState extends State<EditProfile> {

  String firstName = "Sushant";
  late TextEditingController firstNameController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    firstNameController = TextEditingController(text: firstName);
  }
}

@override
void dispose() {
  firstNameController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```

Or use

```
class _EditProfileState extends State<EditProfile> {
        
    String firstName = "Sushant";
    TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController();
        
    @override
    void initState() {
       firstNameController.text = firstName;
    }
}

@override
void dispose() {
   firstNameController.dispose();
   super.dispose();
}
```

Comment: If you need to override `State` methods like `initState()`, `didUpdateWidget()`, `dispose()`, you should add call super class method too. They have `@mustCallSuper` attribute and some code to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to initiate `firstNameController` with a non-constant value. `firstName` here is not static and belongs to the instance.
When the class is created, it cannot access properties of itself because they are not created either (nothing guarantees that `firstName` is created before `firstNameController`).

However, you can use the `late` keyword:

```dart
class _EditProfileState extends State<EditProfile> {

  String firstName = "Sushant";

  late TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController(text: firstName);
}
```

`late` will make `firstNameController` "lazy". It means it is only going to be evaluated when called (and not when your class instance is created). Therefore, when using the `late` keyword, when evaluated, your class is already created with its properties and you can access them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using State, set default text in `initState`.

This will only trigger once when Widget is initialized. Also set all `TextEditingController` as `final`, you should not assign new one later.

Last, remember to dispose it.

```dart
String firstName = "Sushant";
final TextEditingController firstNameController = TextEditingController();

@override
void initState() {
  firstNameController.text = firstName;
  super.initState();
}

@override
void dispose() {
  firstNameController.dispose();
  super.dispose();
}
```